# entityName_ cannot be resolved to a variable, error message in eclipse ide?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, jhipster

In my Jhipster generated file *entityNameQueryService.java* , eclipse indicates the following line as error, but project compiles successfully.
So, this must be the configuration issue with the eclipse ide. Couldn't figure it out myself..

```
        if (criteria.getId() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildSpecification(criteria.getId(), FRCommunications_.id));
        }
```

The error message is

"FRCommunications_ cannot be resolved to a variable"

For your information, FRCommunications is my entity name.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA static metamodel which is used for JPA filtering in JHipster requires generating classes (named like the entity but suffixed with '_') at build time through an annotation processor, this is configured for maven and gradle so you can run a build and it will generate missing classes.

Alternatively, if you don't want to build using maven or gradle see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html#_eclipse

Comment: files were generated in the target folder...how to get rid of compilation issues in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Have you read the doc I linked above? I dont use Eclipse so I can't help more.

Answer (score 4):

For eclipse, After

mvn clean install -nsu

just right click on target/generated-sources/annotation and select "Use as Source Folder"